# IF value meets condition copy paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to go through all values in column P of a table in 'Sheet1':

[image: First Table]

If value is `<1`, I want to copy paste the values in columns with the headings to a table in an 'explanation' sheet:

[image: Second Table]

Comment: Did you try to do it on your own firstly? Also, does it have to be done via VBA? Because this could be also done with Excel formulas.

Comment: Look into [`Index/Match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/), I believe that will get you started on how to get only those values on to another sheet.

Comment: [(If you're curious about the downvotes)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

On the sheet you want the data to go into (table 2) and under your header (in table 2) set the cell equal to the cell you want from table 1. Do this by entering pressing "=" and then clicking to the sheet with table 1 and click on the cell on the first row. Repeat this for the Name, Identifier, Sector, Rate... Once you have the first row done, highlight the cells on the second row and click and hold the bottom right of the black out line and drag down to the same number of rows from table 1.

If you want the values pasted there, then highlight the range and copy and right click paste > paste special (click on paste special) and select values.

Then you can sort the data based on the explanation sheet by the column that's value you need to be less than 1 and delete the rows that are greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what columns you want copied as they are not named in the first table image you have, so I just did up a macro that you can adjust the ranges yourself as you need copied and to what sheet you need.

The below code loops through your data, checks if the data in `Column P` for each row is less than 1 and puts the data into a variable where you can copy and paste to where ever you need that data,

The code,

```
Sub d()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
   Dim rng As Range

   lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 2 To lastrow
      If Range("P" & i).Value < 1 Then
         If Not rng Is Nothing Then
             Set rng = Union(rng, Range("B" & i), Range("C" & i), Range("D" & i), Range("Q" & i), Range("H" & i), Range("I" & i), Range("P" & i))
         Else
             Set rng = Union(Range("B" & i), Range("C" & i), Range("D" & i), Range("Q" & i), Range("H" & i), Range("I" & i), Range("P" & i))
         End If
      End If
   Next
   rng.Copy Sheets("explanation").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

See if this does not help any?